# How to determine test error for Simon Funk's incremental SVD method

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, svd, netflix

I'm trying to implement this for a ratings dataset that's similar to `Netflix`, and I've gotten it to "work"; the training error is driven toward `0` after each iteration / more features are added.

How do I determine how well this will predict a test dataset (of users with a handful of ratings that weren't used for training)? Funk glosses over that part and it's really confusing me.

I started with the following matrices:

1. User Feature Matrix (Users x Num_Features)
2. Movies Feature Matrix (Movies x Num_Features)
3. Ratings Matrix (Movies x Users)

My only way to update the first two matrices is by updating them iteration by iteration in the algorithm. I don't think I can train those matrices, AND THEN introduce a completely new user afterwards and estimate what his feature matrix looks like.

What I've tried now is removing 20% of the ratings from the `Rating Matrix`, moving them into a Test Matrix, and filling in all the empty cells in both with 0's (which are ignored in the cost function). It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> It's not working.

Usually one compute the RMSE on the probe set. Init the features per user by random you get some ''prediction''-values for each user.

Using a crystal ball to interpret what 'It's not working.' means I would say:
You cannot exclude 20% of the ratings by random from the learning set for the probeset. To make a prediction for a user you need at least one rating from the user to get the features.
So you are correct:

> AND THEN introduce a completely new user

is not possible.
Maybe you put all ratings from one user into the probe set and so the user features were not updated by Simon Funk's SVD.